# How to filter a mat-tree component Angular Material 6.0.1

Tags: angular, filter, tree, angular6, angular-material2

I'm using mat-tree angular material component.
It's a nice component with some very useful features like, multi-select, expand all/collapse all.
I was not able to find any tree filtering feature in any of their APIs.
Has anyone came across this feature or done any work around to get mat-tree filter?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a new data source(filtered).

[stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yb37gh?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.html)

I will explain the example of the shared link: I filtered the data with `filter(filterText: string)` in `ChecklistDatabase` and triggered a `dataChange` event. Then `datasource.data` was changed by a handled event in `TreeChecklistExample`. Thus the data source has been modified.

```js
filter(filterText: string) {
  let filteredTreeData;

  if (filterText) {
    filteredTreeData = this.treeData.filter(
      //There is filter function in the sample
    );
  } else {
    filteredTreeData = this.treeData;
  }

  // file node as children.
  const data = this.buildFileTree(filteredTreeData, '0');

  // Notify the change. !!!IMPORTANT
  this.dataChange.next(data);
}
```

Comment: help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578743/how-to-make-mat-tree-component-angular-material-6-0-1

Answer (score 19):

After I have spent several days on the same task here are some tips i can give:
I am using input event to follow the user input:

```html
<input matInput class="form-control" 
  (input)="filterChanged($event.target.value)" 
  placeholder="Search Skill">
```

On this filter I attached a subject so i can subscribe to it:

```js
searchFilter: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
filterChanged(filter: string): void {
  this.searchFilter.next(filter);
}
```

To make it smooth for the user, usually, we want to delay the search execution which you can do with `debounceTime`.

```js
this.searchFilter.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(value => {
    if (value && value.length >= 3) {
      this.filterByName(value);
    } else {
      this.clearFilter();
    }
});
```

To perform the search, I hide and show the nodes using a css class. This is done directly on the presentation collection which is flat and very easy to filter.

```js
treeControl: FlatTreeControl<SkillFlatNode>;
this.treeControl.dataNodes
```

First, I hide all and then show only those that match the criteria. Finally, I want to show their parents, but this is specific for my tree structure.

```js
private filterByName(term: string): void {
  const filteredItems = this.treeControl.dataNodes.filter(
    x => x.value.DisplayName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) === -1
  );
  filteredItems.map(x => {
    x.visible = false;
  });

  const visibleItems = this.treeControl.dataNodes.filter(
    x => x.value.IsSkill &&
    x.value.DisplayName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
  );
  visibleItems.map( x => {
    x.visible = true;
    this.markParent(x);
  });
}
```

Finally, here is the clear filter:

```js
private clearFilter(): void {
  this.treeControl.dataNodes.forEach(x => x.visible = true);
}
```

Don't make the same mistake like I did and try to filter the input collection (`this.dataSource.data` in my case) because you will lose your selection or you will have to map it back to the presentation.
Here is my initial data:

```js
this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
  this.transformer, this._getLevel, this._isExpandable, this._getChildren
);
this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<SkillFlatNode>(
  this._getLevel, this._isExpandable
);
this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(
  this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener
);

skillService.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
  this.dataSource.data = data;
});
```

Comment: How is your datasource structured. Would like to know how markParent will work.

Comment: The key point is not to filter dataSource.data. Rather have a property on dataNodes to drive the display using ngClass/ngStyle.

Comment: This seems like the way to go, just I don't know how to use the visible filter? 
If I add when: it breaks apart...

Comment: You just saved my life... It works

Answer (score 16):

[Stackblitz link for mat-tree filter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tree-with-checkbox-and-a-filter?file=src/app/tree-checklist-example.html)

If Anyone need to visually filter the mat tree without modifying the datasource, then go for this solution.

Basically the idea is to hide the nodes which are not part of the search string.

Input field

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchString" />
```

call filter function for leaf node(this is done in the first mat-tree-node)

```
<mat-tree-node
   *matTreeNodeDef="let node"
   [style.display]="
      filterLeafNode(node) ? 'none' : 'block'
   "
   .....
   ......
```

call filter function for the nodes other than leaf node(this is done in the second mat-tree-node)

```
<mat-tree-node
   *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild"
   [style.display]="filterParentNode(node) ? 'none' : 'block'"
   .....
   .....
```

filterLeafNode  function

```
filterLeafNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
   if (!this.searchString) {
     return false
   }
   return node.item.toLowerCase()
     .indexOf(this.searchString?.toLowerCase()) === -1
}
```

filterParentNode function

```
filterParentNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {

  if (    
    !this.searchString ||
    node.item.toLowerCase()
     .indexOf(
       this.searchString?.toLowerCase()
     ) !== -1
  ) {
    return false
  }
  const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node)

  if (
    descendants.some(
      (descendantNode) =>
        descendantNode.item
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.searchString?.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    )
  ) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: You're a life savior!

Comment: Beautiful approach!

Comment: Doesn't this approach constantly call both the filter functions all the time? If you put a console.log in either of the filter functions I am seeing the consoles fire endlessly. Overall I thought putting function calls in templates like that is a bad idea as change detection is unable to detect changes in value (unless you are creating some sort of pure pipe)

Comment: @JakeTheBraekjust yes this will be called every time when there is a change detection in angular. And the improvement for this would be to use pure pipes as you said

Answer (score 6):

I am able to filter a tree by using simple recursion. Below are the code snippets:

The `filter()` function is called on `(keyup)` of `input type="text"`. `cloneDeep` function is imported from lodash `import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';`

`this.searchString` is the string value for the filter text.

```
  filter() {
    const clonedTreeLocal = cloneDeep(this.clonedTree);
    this.recursiveNodeEliminator(clonedTreeLocal);
    this.dataSource.data = clonedTreeLocal;
    this.treeControl.expandAll();
  }
```

The tree structure is defined by the interface

```
export interface ITreeDataStructure {
    Id?: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    children?: Array<ITreeDataStructure>;
}
```

The actual filtering is done by the function `recursiveNodeEliminator`

```
recursiveNodeEliminator(tree: Array<ITreeDataStructure>): boolean {
    for (let index = tree.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
      const node = tree[index];
      if (node.children) {
        const parentCanBeEliminated = this.recursiveNodeEliminator(node.children);
        if (parentCanBeEliminated) {
          if (node.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchString.toLocaleLowerCase()) === -1) {
            tree.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      } else {
        // Its a leaf node. No more branches.
        if (node.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchString.toLocaleLowerCase()) === -1) {
          tree.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    return tree.length === 0;
  }
```

Comment: Great! Work like a charm in flat tree with virtual scroll and thousands of nodes...

Comment: Awesome. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is for Model Filters. Create 2 lists, one to store all your data and one to be used as a datasource.

```
 SearchCategory(searchText){
      this.searchText=searchText;
      this.categories=this.categoryNameSearch(this.AllCategories,searchText)
      this.dataSource.data = this.categories;
    }
    categoryNameSearch(categorys:Category[],searchText):Category[]{
      let category:Category[];
      category=categorys.filter(f=>this.converter(f.name).includes(this.converter(searchText)))
      categorys.forEach(element => {
        this.categoryNameSearch(element.childrens,searchText).forEach(e=>category.push(e))
      });
      return category;
    }
    converter(text) {
      var trMap = {
          'çÇ':'c',
          'ğĞ':'g',
          'şŞ':'s',
          'üÜ':'u',
          'ıİ':'i',
          'öÖ':'o'
      };
      for(var key in trMap) {
          text = text.replace(new RegExp('['+key+']','g'), trMap[key]);
      }
      return  text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/ig, '') // remove non-alphanumeric chars
                  .replace(/\s/gi, "-") // convert spaces to dashes
                  .replace(/[-]+/gi, "-") // trim repeated dashes
                  .toLowerCase();
    
    }
```

Html Side

```
  <input type="text" (ngModelChange)="SearchCategory($event)" placeholder="Search Category" class="form-control"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension to @Amith B answer to expand or to collapse

```
filterParentNode(node: treeviewNode): boolean {
 if (!this.searchString || node.name.toLowerCase()
  .indexOf(this.searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
   if (this.searchString != undefined) {
      if (this.searchString.length == 1 || this.searchString == "") {
        this.treeControl.collapseAll();
        this.searchString = undefined;
      }
    }
  return false;
}
const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
if (descendants.some((descendantNode) => descendantNode.name.toLowerCase()
.indexOf(this.searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1)) {
  this.treeControl.expand(node);
  return false;
}
return true;}
```

Full credits goes to @Amith B

Answer (score -1):

First add an input as the filter in the view. Bind keyup event to rxjs Subject

```
<input type="text" matInput placeholder="search" #filter (keyup)="keyEvent.next($event)" [(ngModel)]="keyword">
```

Then query your backend to filter the tree node with keyword

```
this.keyEvent.pipe(
  map((e: any) => e.target.value.toLowerCase()),
  debounceTime(500),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap((keyword: string) => {
    if (keyword && keyword.length > 2) {
      return this.yourservice.searchForData(this.entId, keyword);
    } else {
      return of();
    }
  })
)
.subscribe((r) => {
  this.nestedDataSource.data = r;
  this.nestedTreeControl.dataNodes = r;
  this.nestedTreeControl.expandAll();
});
```

Comment: This is just offloading the filtering to the back-end. It does not perform any filtering in the tree itself (i.e. on the front-end).